# обновить позицию вертекса в треугольнике после смены нормали

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

У меня есть треугольник, его нормаль 0.0, 1.0, 0.0. Есть вертекс внутри этого треугольника, известны позиции вершин треугольника и позиция  вертекса. В моем случае нормаль высот треугольника меняется на новую (неизвестную) и мне нужно вычислить новое положение данного вертекса - все координаты в глобальной системе, использую с++. Я бы хотел получить правильно направление хода мыслей.

Comment: У вас терминология .. странная. Что такое вертекс внутри треугольника? Что такое нормаль высот треугольника?

Answer (score 0):

вертекс это точка, которая лежит в плоскости треугольника, нормали высот треугольника определяют его лицевую сторону, в моем случае они не сглажены. Я действительно не до конца обрисовал ситуацию, я крайне редко выхожу "в эфир" с вопросами, извиняюсь. В моем случае требовалась формула нахождения пересечения двух линий (одна линия из одной из высот по вектору расстояния между этой высотой и точкой, другая линия представляет из себя противолежащую этой высоте грань), а именно точка пересечения на противолежащей грани, в случае изменения нормали треугольника достаточно будет определить вектор между вершиной исхода и этой точкой, и по сохраненному расстоянию между вершиной исхода и точкой в плоскости треугольника рассчитать её новое местоположение - так бы я обозначил теоретическое решение, поскольку я применил другой метод не предусматривающий ситуации описанной в теме вопроса. Извиняюсь за туманность изложения.

Comment: Используйте "правку", для редактирования и дополнения вопроса.